# Htaccess and redirect all content of folder, but exlude the main folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I got the following urls:

1. **domain.com/categoryA/articleA**
2. **domain.com/categoryA/articleB**

I want to redirect:

**domain.com/categoryA/articleA** -> **domain.com/categoryB/articleA**

**domain.com/categoryA/articleB** -> **domain.com/categoryB/articleB**

but leave it as it is and do not redirect the main folder: **domain.com/categoryA/**

I tried to use the rule:

`RewriteRule ^categoryA/(.*)$ /categoryB/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

but it also redirect **domain.com/categoryA/** to **domain.com/categoryB/**

How to exclude from the above rewrite rule the redirection of the main folder (categoryA), but still redirect all that is in the folder (and then change also the root folder)?

I am looking for a solution that is SEO friendly (I got the same articles in two categories, but want still to have indexed domain.com/categoryA, but the rest only as domain.com/categoryB/xxx.

Best Greetings,
Mat

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following Rules in your .htaccess file. Please make sure to place this rule under your domain redirect rule(if its there), also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^categoryA/([\w-]+)/?$ /categoryB/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```